# Running cqlsh in fips mode

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Has anyone had luck running cqlsh in fips mode? We are trying to get it working and get the following error.

--

```
[root@pb03 ~]# /opt/cassandra/bin/cqlsh 10.50.50.103
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 147, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 109, in __get_openssl_constructor
    return __get_builtin_constructor(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 97, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/apache-cassandra-2.2.9/bin/cqlsh.py", line 148, in <module>
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
  File "/opt/apache-cassandra-2.2.9/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.5.0.post0-d8d0456.zip/cassandra-driver-3.5.0.post0-d8d0456/cassandra/cluster.py", line 62, in <module>
  File "/opt/apache-cassandra-2.2.9/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.5.0.post0-d8d0456.zip/cassandra-driver-3.5.0.post0-d8d0456/cassandra/metadata.py", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name md5
[root@pb03 ~]# 
[root@pb03 ~]# python -V
Python 2.7.10
[root@pb03 ~]#
```

--

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

rebuilding & installing python with _md5 fixed the issue for us.